# Cannot find module '@babel/parser'

Tags: javascript, npm, babeljs

I am no longer able to transpile my codebase when running `babel`. I made. It wasn't happening before and I am unable to figure out why. This only happened when I pulled remote master branch, which had `yarn.lock` conflicts. I resolved conflicts with the `yarn` commands.

here is part of my `package.json`

```
{
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/cli": "^7.1.0",
    "@babel/core": "^7.1.2",
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties": "^7.0.0",
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-decorators": "^7.0.0",
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-export-default-from": "^7.0.0",
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-export-namespace-from": "^7.0.0",
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-function-sent": "^7.0.0",
    "@babel/plugin-transform-runtime": "^7.1.0",
    "@babel/polyfill": "^7.0.0",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.1.0",
    "@babel/preset-react": "^7.0.0",
    "@babel/register": "^7.0.0",
    ...
  }
}
```

Running `babel src -d build` results in the following error

```
{ Error: Cannot find module '@babel/parser'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:548:15)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:475:25)
    at Module.require (module.js:597:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:11:18)
    at _parser (/Users/mohammadmohammad/Dev/work/procore/hydra_clients/budgetViewer/node_modules/@babel/core/lib/transformation/normalize-file.js:59:16)
    at parser (/Users/mohammadmohammad/Dev/work/procore/hydra_clients/budgetViewer/node_modules/@babel/core/lib/transformation/normalize-file.js:170:18)
    at normalizeFile (/Users/mohammadmohammad/Dev/work/procore/hydra_clients/budgetViewer/node_modules/@babel/core/lib/transformation/normalize-file.js:138:11)
    at runSync (/Users/mohammadmohammad/Dev/work/procore/hydra_clients/budgetViewer/node_modules/@babel/core/lib/transformation/index.js:44:43)
    at runAsync (/Users/mohammadmohammad/Dev/work/procore/hydra_clients/budgetViewer/node_modules/@babel/core/lib/transformation/index.js:35:14)
    at /Users/mohammadmohammad/Dev/work/procore/hydra_clients/budgetViewer/node_modules/@babel/core/lib/transform-file.js:58:36 code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND' }
```

I also tried deleting `node_modules` and run `yarn install` with no luck.

Comment: did you delete your locked package json file?

Comment: This might be a stupid question, but why not `yarn add @babel/parser`?

Comment: @JoeFitzsimmons i did not. I checked `yarn.lock` and `@babel/parser` indeed exists

Comment: @ChrisG  babel/parser is a dependency in babel/core and i shouldn't have to or be installing it directly in my project.

Comment: @ChrisG, I checked all the comments and even the solution and it did not work for my situation, but yours did. Thank you.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Was able to resolve the issue by simply bumping `babel-eslint` from `8.2,3` to `10.0.1`

Comment: You should mark this answer as the correct solution then

Comment: But how did you do this - what command upgrades the version you are using?

Answer (score 12):

For me the solution was to delete the *node_modules* folder, and reinstall

```
rm -rf node_modules
yarn
```

Comment: This worked for me! I think its because I was switching node versions up and down

Answer (score 4):

This is what worked for me:

`yarn add -D @babel/parser`

OR with `NPM`

`npm i -D @babel/parser`

Good Luck...

Answer (score 0):

Below command worked for me

npm audit fix --force

Please note that audit fix install SemVer-major updates to toplevel dependencies, not just SemVer-compatible ones (https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v7/commands/npm-audit)